# recycle view and cursor adapter view holder

Tags: android, listview, view, cursor, android-viewholder

In my application I have used both a recycle view and a cursor adapter in order to publish information to a list view format.

The current problem I'm facing is that I'm trying to setup a view holder in the code below so that when the user changes the state of a switch then it stores it in the view holder.

Currently in my code whenever the user selects the switch it will change the database value to either true or false for the switch to work. But when the user scrolls up or down the switch will reset.

I was wondering if anyone had any advice in implementing a view holder to store a switch state.

```
public AlarmRecyclerAdapter(Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

    mContext = context;

    mCursorAdapter = new CursorAdapter(mContext, cursor, 0) {
        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

            rootView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.temp_layout3, parent, false);

            return rootView;

        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

            mView = view;
            mCursor = cursor;

     /*  My layout views */

     custom_alarm_switch = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.selectedContacts);

    /*  Get information from database */

            final String switchState = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("switch_state"));

            position = cursor.getPosition();

    /*  Set information */

            custom_alarm_switch.setChecked(Boolean.valueOf(switchState));

            cursor.moveToPosition(position);


}

public static class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    TextView header;
    Switch custom_alarm_switch;



    public Viewholder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        custom_alarm_switch = (Switch) itemView.findViewById(R.id.selectedContacts);


    }


}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = mCursorAdapter.newView(mContext, mCursorAdapter.getCursor(), parent);

    return new Viewholder(view);


}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    mCursorAdapter.getCursor().moveToPosition(position);

    mCursorAdapter.bindView(holder.itemView, mContext, mCursorAdapter.getCursor());

}





@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mCursorAdapter.getCount();
}
```

Comment: this is because your cursor is immutable: either you have to call `CursorAdapter#changeCursor` with the new cursor which is heavy thing or use a `CursorWrapper` and override `getInt` method - btw better use [this](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b) adapter as it is `Filterable` and supports `FilterQueryProvider`

Comment: Thank you for answering, so you're proposing that I swap the cursor each time a switch has been selected on my list view? Instead of swapping the cursor is there a way of implementing a view holder solution?

Comment: thats why i said it is a hard and heavy just to create a new cursor when one column in one row changes - and yes you can use for example `SparseBooleanArray` in your `onBindViewHolder` - in your switch listener when it changes to "ON" add an entry to the array and when it goes to "OFF" remove it

Comment: actually you cannot remove it - you have to set the value to `false`

Comment: I like the idea of implementing the array list. Could you provide any example as I've never used a SpareBooleanArray? In my head now I no how to get all the true and false values for each row. But I don't no how to apply it to the recycleview. Once the list view is reading the array list for the true and false value I can simply remove and add items

Comment: use `indexOfKey`, `get` / `valueAt` and `put` methods

Comment: still cannot get my head around this solution

Comment: so what problems did you face with `SparseBooleanArray`? whats your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151911/discussion-between-steven-and-pskink).